# QGIS couldn't commit changes to layer on a database

Tags: qgis, editing

i'm using QGIS on a database with a team,so all of our changes can be viewed at anytime 
but sometimes we run into an issue sometimes when we save an error "couldn't commit changes" shows up and we have to exit the program and re-open it and start again from the last save point.. is there any particular reason why is this happening? any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: very hard to guess without any technical details!

Comment: What database type are you using (PostgreSQL, sqlite)?

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to export this layer to the file. Once loaded after saving, everything should work fine.